# Standard citation: Does an out of range call to `vector::operator[]` invoke Undefined Behavior?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Consider:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector <int> v;
  v.reserve (100);
  v[1] = 42;
}
```

I am aware that the above code invokes Undefined Behavior, because at the call-site for `v[1]`, the size of the vector according to `v.size()` is < 1. (It is zero.)

However I have spent the last hour or so looking through the C++ Standard for a citation that either directly or indirectly clarifies that this is, in fact, Undefined Behavior.

Maybe I have missed the obvious.  Can you provide a citation or citations from at least the C++03 and optionally the C++11 Standard which clears this up?

Comment: Note that there may be no citation.  Anythhing that falls out of the scope of what is specified in the Standard is Undefined Behavior.  This might be one of those cases, but it seemed unlikely to me.

Comment: §23.2.3 Table 101, on "Operational Semantics" for `a[i]`: `*(a.begin() + n)`. If `n >= a.size()`, the computed iterator is past-the-end and dereferencing that is UB according to §24.2.1/5.

Comment: @Xeo:  That is exactly what I was looking for.  Please post so I can UV and Accept.

Comment: Sorry, already edited into Nicol's answer. Didn't see your comment until now. :)

Comment: @Xeo:  Oh, well I guess you're going to miss out on 15 points. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an outgrowth of how `operator[]` is defined. In §23.2.3 [sequence.rqmts] Table 101, the Operational Semantics of `operator[]` is defined as `*(a.begin() + n)`. So it's defined in terms of iterators. And incrementing `begin` past `end` and dereferencing it is undefined behavior according to §24.2.1/5 [iterator.requirements.general].

Comment: Thanks.  I knew that much, but then I had a hard time finding where incrementing past `end` was listed as UB.  @Xeo seems to have provided that information in the comments to the OP.

Comment: This also raised another question in my mind when reading through this section originally.  Are "Operational Semantics" normative?  Or are they line "Notes" which are non-normative?  That might be a seperate question, and I can research myself first.

Comment: @JohnDibling: I don't see how they can be anything *but* normative. They describe how those expressions behave, and it's described nowhere else.

Comment: @JohnDibling: All text in the standard is assumed to be normative unless otherwise stated (as in [note: sections]).

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your underlying question, but your vector isn't of size 0, it is of size 100 (since you created it with the size constructor)

The man page for `std::vector` does claim it's undefined behaviour, but I don't know if you consider that to be "good enough" (you asked for a citation from the c++ standard)

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Alloc = std::allocator<_Tp>> reference std::vector< _Tp, _Alloc >::operator[] (size_type__n)
   [inline]
   Subscript access to the data contained in the vector. Parameters:
       n The index of the element for which data should be accessed.

   Returns:
       Read/write reference to data.

   This operator allows for easy, array-style, data access. Note that data access with this operator is unchecked and
   out_of_range lookups are not defined. (For checked lookups see at().)

   Definition at line 695 of file stl_vector.h.
```

Comment: Sorry, but the original version of my question had a major typo in it.  Please reload the question and take another look.  Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Also, yes, I was looking for an actual Standard citation.  Like I said, I already *knew* that it was UB.  I wanted to be able to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

`a[n]` (where `a` is a vector and `n` is an integer) is defined in Table 101 in 23.2.3p16 as `*(a.begin() + n)`.

23.3.6.1p1 says that "vector... supports random access iterators." Table 111 in 24.2.7p1 defines `a + n` (where `a` is a random access iterator) in terms of `a += n`, which in turn is defined as being equivalent to `n` repeated evaluations of `++a`.

Table 107 in 24.2.3p2 defines the expression `++r` (where `r` is an input iterator) with the precondition that "`r` is dereferenceable".

23.2.1p6 ...end() returns an iterator which is the past-the-end value for the container. If the container is empty, then begin() == end().

Note that, in your example, `v` is indeed empty. This simplifies the proof; otherwise, more citations would be needed to show that applying `operator++` repeatedly `v.size()` times to `v.begin()` would produce `v.end()`.

24.2.1p5 ...The library never assumes that past-the-end values are dereferenceable...