# Is taking the address of std::vector::operator[](size) Undefined Behavior in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

Is this undefined behavior?

```
ptrdiff_t one() {
   std::vector<int> test(1);
   return &test[1] - &test[0];
}
```

Is this undefined behavior?

```
ptrdiff_t zero() {
   std::vector<int> test;
   int * end = &test[0];
   int * begin = &test[0];
   return end - begin;
}
```

If either of these are undefined behavior, can anyone help me locate the section in the C++11 spec where it describes that the subscript operator of a vector must be called on a value less than (rather than less than or equal to) size, or vice versa?

Thanks

Comment: I found that for valarray<T> "6 If the subscript operator is invoked with a size_t argument whose value is not less than the length of the array, the behavior is undefined."  in 26.6.2.4 -- I'm curious why that kind of clarity doesn't exist for vector. 

I definitely searched for a while and found a lot of related questions, but not about this particular nuance: and I think if it's not undefined behavior that it's new for C++11.

Comment: @sehe: `std::vector` != C-style array.

Comment: @Xeo I'm aware of that. I'd have removed that - but somehow that comment was not shown on my browser. (I probably back-buttoned it)

Comment: @hellcatv: `valarray` is not defined with the _containers_, whose definitions are stated rather more nebulously.

Comment: I've found [the real dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17731133/560648).

Comment: The solution to your problem is `&vec.data()[0]` and `&vec.data()[1]` I think -- or just `vec.data()` and `vec.data()+1` even better.  The rules barring dereferencing of an iterator don't apply to pointers, and in general if you want to access the "raw pointers" to the data in a vector, use `data()`.  This even handles the empty vector case.

Comment: As for "finding the real dupe"...you found a different question that had the same answer. Actually dereferencing the item off the end of the vector and assigning to it is a lot less common an idiom than someone who wants to just do pointer math on the resulting &myvector[myvector.size()] - &myvector[0] (which usually works in practice, despite being undefined behavior--so this would be news to those folks). Also the 'duplicate' poster chose an example where the item was 2 out of range...and C allows Carray address calculation at exactly the end explicitly for pointer math.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, those program fragments have undefined behaviour.**

Table 101 defines `test[0]` as `*(test.begin() + 0)`, which is invalid if you have no elements:

> `[C++11: 24.2.1/5]:` Just as a regular pointer to an array guarantees that there is a pointer value pointing past the last element of the array, so for any iterator type there is an iterator value that points past the last element of a corresponding sequence. These values are called *past-the-end* values. Values of an iterator `i` for which the expression `*i` is defined are called *dereferenceable*. **The library never assumes that past-the-end values are dereferenceable.** *[..]*

Table 106 states dereferenceability as a pre-requisite for the validity of `*i`, given any iterator `i`.

It doesn't matter that you try to take the address afterwards: you've already broken your program. For example, your standard library implementation may compliantly trigger an assertion from `operator*` for any past-the-end iterator.